# invalid default value (mysql 5.7) for timestamp field

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

EDIT:
When updating an existing database from mysql 5.6 and executing:

`UPDATE phppos_register_log SET shift_end = '2015-01-01 00:00:00' WHERE shift_end = '0000-00-00 00:00:00';`

This produces:

```
#1292 - Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for column 'shift_end' at row 1
#1067 - Invalid default value for 'shift_start'
```

This worked in mysql <=5.7. I couldn't find any documentation about this...What is the issue with this?

```
CREATE TABLE `phppos_register_log` (
      `register_log_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `employee_id_open` int(10) NOT NULL,
      `employee_id_close` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `register_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `shift_start` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
      `shift_end` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
      `open_amount` decimal(23,10) NOT NULL,
      `close_amount` decimal(23,10) NOT NULL,
      `cash_sales_amount` decimal(23,10) NOT NULL,
      `total_cash_additions` decimal(23,10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000000000',
      `total_cash_subtractions` decimal(23,10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000000000',
      `notes` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
      `deleted` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      PRIMARY KEY (`register_log_id`),
      KEY `phppos_register_log_ibfk_1` (`employee_id_open`),
      KEY `phppos_register_log_ibfk_2` (`register_id`),
      KEY `phppos_register_log_ibfk_3` (`employee_id_close`),
      CONSTRAINT `phppos_register_log_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`employee_id_open`) REFERENCES `phppos_employees` (`person_id`),
      CONSTRAINT `phppos_register_log_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`register_id`) REFERENCES `phppos_registers` (`register_id`),
      CONSTRAINT `phppos_register_log_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`employee_id_close`) REFERENCES `phppos_employees` (`person_id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: This issue *is* documented... but first, *which release* of MySQL 5.7 are you using (particularly relevant, since 5.7 isn't yet GA as of now)? and there was an ill-conceived change introduced in 5.7.4 that was reverted in 5.7.8, that would explain this.  Please confirm your version.

Comment: mysql-5.7.8-rc-osx10.9-x86_64.dmg

Comment: I posted an edit with another issue. This seems like a real issue with mysql 5.7.8

Comment: Further review of the [5.7.8 release notes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-8.html) suggests that one change was reverted, but that you may need to to remove `NO_ZERO_DATE`, which is now part of the default configuration.  Can you confirm? Please `SELECT @@SQL_MODE;`.

Comment: Yes I changed the mode and that worked. I found a lot of things mysql 5.7 added which caused issue so I set the mode to ""; this seems like a pretty big update with a lot of changes.

Answer (score 8):

since mysql 5.7, `SQL_MODE` default value is `strict`, please view this page:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192027/invalid-default-value-for-create-date-timestamp-field